# Trying to implement a finder function using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to fine the kth smallest value in x selected using a random splitter,
using recusion, I have already done this without recursion but I am explicitly trying to find it with using recursion. I am faced with a       `x = x[1,len(x)] ValueError: ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)`

```
    splitter = random.randrange(0,len(x))
    ants = x[splitter]
    lilz = []
    bigz = []
    for pigs in x:
        if pigs >= ants:
            bigz.append(pigs)
        elif pigs == ants:
            splitter
        else:
            lilz.append(pigs)
    if k == splitter:
        s = x[splitter]
    elif k < splitter:
        s =  selectR(lilz,k)
    else:
        s = selectR(bigz, k - ( len(lilz) + 1))
    return s
```

Comment: 1. You should keep the `import` statements in the global scope (i.e. outside the function). x is not defined on line 3 and hence `len(x)` too is not defined.

Comment: `x[:len(x)-1]` can (and should) be written as `x[:-1]`

Comment: Did these things thanks guys, now for some reason I still get the same error. I put importing random outside the function body is there anything else you think I should also put? The error signifies that the x list is empty but idk why it becomes empty before the kth smallest value is found.

Comment: Is it a given that `x` is sorted, and that all values are unique? If not, then when given an `x` like `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]`, which value is expected for `k==3`? Both `1` and `3` might fit the problem definition, it's unclear which is correct.

Comment: x is not sorted, that is why I have the for pigs in x for loop to sort the larger list into the smaller pieces. Not all values are unique however, but if there are multiple of the kth smallest, one becomes the splitter value and the rest are put into the bigz list.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping over the values in `x` and splitting it into two lists, just sort `x` the first time it's given to us, and then your evaluations become easier. You COULD sort it every time, but if we add a 3rd parameter defaulted to `False`, we can indicate on recursive calls that it's already sorted and save some work:

```
import random

def selR(x, k, is_sorted=False):
    """Returns: The kth smallest value in x selected using a random splitter,
    using RECURSION.

    Parameter x: list of values
    Precondition: x contains ints or floats and len(x) > 0

    Parameter k: the rank of the value we want to find
    Precondition: k is an int in [1..n] where n is the length of x."""


    if not is_sorted:
        x = sorted(x)

    if len(x) == 1 or k <= 1:
        """
            1) Does x only have one item? Then it doesn't 
               really matter what k is, we're done.
            2) Is k <= 1? If so, then we don't need to split anymore - 
               the head of the sorted list is the desired value.
        """
        return x[0]

    """3) Find a splitter in the defined range - [1..n] where n is the length of x"""
    splitter = random.randrange(1,len(x))

    if splitter == k:
        """
            4) Is splitter the same as k? If so, we've found our value; 
              just return the tail of split list. return x[k-1]
        """
        return x[k-1]
    elif splitter > k:
        """
            5) Is splitter larger than k? If so, the kth smallest value is found
               before the split, so we recurse with selR(x[1:splitter], k-1) - we
               can start at x[1] and reduce k by one, because if x[0] was the
               kth smallest value, we would have already returned it in step 2.
        """
        return selR(x[1:splitter], k-1, True)
    else:
        """
            6) Is splitter smaller than k? Then the kth smallest value is found
               after the split return selR(x[splitter:], k-len(x[0:splitter])) -
               that is, remove items before splitter from x and reduce k by the number
               of items we just removed.
        """
        return selR(x[splitter:], k-len(x[0:splitter]), True)

# Test case
x = [1,2,1,3,4,5]
for k in range(1,len(x)+1):
    ord = { 1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd" }.get(k if (k < 20) else (k % 10), 'th')
    print(f"{k}{ord} smallest element of {x}:", selR(x, k))
```